# Table vs View vs Materialized View

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm currently learning PostgreSQL. However, I am a little bit confused about table, view, and materialized view. I understand the basic definitions as well as conceptions. But sometimes, I have a trouble to make a decision that I should create a table, a view, or materialized view. Would anyone share some experience how to apply it correctly? What are the pros and cons of one over the others?

Comment: this is more general than postgresql - same patterns apply in most relational databases

Answer (score 58):

A table is where data is stored.  You always start with tables first, and then your usage pattern dictates whether you need views or materialized views.

A view is like a stored query for future use, if you're frequently joining or filtering the same tables the same way in multiple places.

A materialized view is like a combination of both: it's a table that is automatically populated and refreshed via a view.  You'd use this if you were using views, and want to pre-join or pre-aggregate the rows to speed up queries.

Comment: "You always start with tables first, and then your usage patter dictates whether you need view or materialized views." <--- This

Comment: If you use Open-High-Low-Close queries (OHLC) that reduce the number of rows by aggregation (FIRST(), MIN(), MAX() etc.) you got a good candidate for a materialized view, [source](https://www.timescale.com/blog/how-postgresql-views-and-materialized-views-work-and-how-they-influenced-timescaledb-continuous-aggregates/)

Answer (score 29):

[This article](https://www.compose.com/articles/its-a-view-its-a-table-no-its-a-materialized-view/) has a nice explanation on this part. Quoting from it,

> When you query a TABLE, you fetch its data directly. On the other
>   hand, when you query a VIEW, you are basically querying another query
>   that is stored in the VIEW's definition.
>
> ...
>
> Between the two there is MATERIALIZED VIEW - it's a VIEW that has a
>   query in its definition and uses this query to fetch the data directly
>   from the storage, but it also has it's own storage that basically acts
>   as a cache in between the underlying TABLE(s) and the queries
>   operating on the MATERIALIZED VIEW. It can be refreshed, just like an
>   invalidated cache - a process that would cause its definition's query
>   to be executed again against the actual data.